# Libgdx cannot load texture issue

Tags: java, libgdx

Cannot load any texture, it worked fine, now it doesn't work, don't know why.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class MiJuego implements ApplicationListener {
public Texture textura = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("prueba.png"));

@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.alex.version1.MiJuego.(MiJuego.java:16)     at
>   com.alex.version1.Main.main(Main.java:14)

Line 16 is exactly the one in which I create the texture.
I have tested it in several projects but it doesn't work. The images are set in the asset folder in my android project.

Comment: please post the entire stack trace

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
public class MiJuego implements ApplicationListener {
public Texture textura;

@Override
public void create() {
    textura = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("prueba.png"))
    ...
}
```

You were creating the Texture at the load time of the **ApplicationListener**, not create time. Libgdx isn't initialized then. So any **Gdx.xxx** call will throw a **NullPointerException**.

Comment: Right, I'm too stupid, didn't realize :P So I just can use that texture inside of a create method?

Comment: Inside and after the create method of the ApplicationListener :) After that, libgdx is initialized and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Btw if you found the answer useful, consider accepting it :)